# Как передать клик по кнопке в ссылке?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Можно ли как-то при переходе по ссылке с одной страницы сайта на другую передать событие клика по кнопке на второй странице?

Есть ссылка такого вида

```
<a href="index.html#anchor"></a> В ней нужно передать клик по кнопке -->

<button id="anchor"></button> которая находится на другой странице.
```

Подскажите как это можно сделать при помощи JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно. На странице, куда происходит переход и где кнопка, размещаете примерно такой код:

```
let anchor = document.getElementById('anchor');
anchor.onclick = function(){
   alert(1);
   //вместо alert пишете то, что должно происходить по клику
};

let href = window.location.href.split('#').pop();
if(href == 'anchor') {
  anchor.onclick();
}
```

Но можно ведь сделать проще - не имитировать клик, а сразу совершать событие, которое должно происходить по клику:

```
let href = window.location.href.split('#').pop();
if(href == 'anchor') {
  //здесь то, что должно происходить
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let href = window.location.href.split('#').pop();
if(href == 'anchor') {
  //Тема 'RolePlay биография гражданина Василия Сердюк' https://[...]
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]